# Nemo File Quick View

Tags: nemo

I changed from Nautilus to Nemo on my Ubuntu 20.04 and I really miss sushi functionality (pressing space bar and having a quick look on the file).
I'snt there any way to have the same feature on Nemo?
Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

LinuxMint has a fork of GNOME Sushi. They call it [`nemo-preview`](https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo-extensions/tree/master/nemo-preview).

It may be installed by obtaining the needed packages manually:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://packages.linuxmint.com/pool/backport/n/nemo-preview/nemo-preview_4.6.0+ulyana_amd64.deb
wget http://packages.linuxmint.com/pool/backport/x/xreader/gir1.2-xreader_2.8.3+ulyssa_amd64.deb
wget http://packages.linuxmint.com/pool/backport/x/xreader/libxreaderview3_2.8.3+ulyssa_amd64.deb
wget http://packages.linuxmint.com/pool/backport/x/xreader/libxreaderdocument3_2.8.3+ulyssa_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get install ./gir1.2-xreader_2.8.3+ulyssa_amd64.deb ./libxreaderdocument3_2.8.3+ulyssa_amd64.deb ./libxreaderview3_2.8.3+ulyssa_amd64.deb ./nemo-preview_4.6.0+ulyana_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get install gir1.2-gtksource-3.0
```

Then you have to restart Nemo by `nemo -q`, launch it again, select file, hit <kbd>Space</kbd> and enjoy.

Comment: Thank you for the answer my friend. Did all the steps and they seemed to have worked fine. I even rebooted the system but it didn't work. I hit space and nothing happens. Is there other step I should do? Thank you again.

Comment: Oh, really you need one extra package - run `sudo apt-get install gir1.2-gtksource-3.0` and retry.

Comment: My friend! It did work like a charm! Thank you for the support! Cheers!

Comment: Great! So you can accept my answer here (checkmark in the left of the answer) :)

Comment: @N0rbert delivers again! Upvote for the only working solution found after hours searching. My dismay is only in finding up/down keys don't work to display images dynamically. Can only hit spacebar again to clear, then navigate, then hit spacebar, etc. Is there any way to get full usability as with sushi, and without installing the entire Mint DE?

Comment: @u2n I updated package versions in the above answer. I solved this problem on package level. Not sure about functionality.

Comment: Thanks @N0rbert, glad to know I'm not doing something wrong. But this really doesn't make sense: The (gutted) nautilus works beautifully (w/ gnome-sushi), updating the previewed image dynamically with navigation until the spacebar closes the preview window, while the full-featured nemo (the old nautilus before gutting) only previews images one-by-one (w/ nemo-preview) in a clunky spacebar-spacebar-navigate cadence. Even with a fresh Mint install, to get the smooth sushi operation, one must install gnome-sushi -- which pulls in nautilus: Anathema!

Comment: I just wish that with a preview open, you could use arrow keys to switch which file is being previewed. Any ideas?

Comment: SADLY, on 21.10 the solution does not work.

Comment: it's black magaic - but it works for me on Linux Mint `THANKS`